# Rails routing is being wonky with IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, routes

Wanting to play with jQuery, Orbited, and FasterCSV, I made a Rails chat application.

You can browse to a URL and there is a chat window that is similar to IRC. You can also export the contents of the chat window by visiting the same URL but adding a ".csv" extension to the URL.

HTML version: `http://host.name/channel/sweetchatroom`

CSV version: `http://host.name/channel/sweetchatroom.csv`

In Firefox, Safari, and Chrome it works normal. In IE, If I visit the "HTML" URL, I get the CSV version of the page. I have to manually add ".html" to the URL like so:

```
http://host.name/channel/sweetchatroom.html
```

My route currently looks like this:

```
map.chat '/channel/:name.:format', :controller => 'channels', :action => 'show'
```

I Googled a bit and tried the following suggestions:

```
map.slug '/channel/:slug.:format', :controller => 'channels', :action => 'show', :defaults => {:format => 'html'}
```

-- and --

```
map.slug '/channel/:slug.:format', :controller => 'channels', :action => 'show', :format => 'html'
```

Neither of them worked. Apparently, if you visit a URL without specifying the format, Rails does not set `params[:format]` to anything. Which in principle I prefer, but the docs are pretty clear that you can set a default format and I'm not sure why it doesn't honor this. The ":defaults => ..." suggestion is what is in the Rails docs.

In order to get it to work I had to change this part of my channels controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { 
    send_data channel_to_csv(@channel),
      :type => "text/plain",
      :filename => "#{@channel.slug}.csv",
      :disposition => 'inline'
  } 
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @channel }
end
```

To this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { 
    send_data channel_to_csv(@channel),
      :type => "text/plain",
      :filename => "#{@channel.slug}.csv",
      :disposition => 'inline'
  } if params[:format] == 'csv' # <-- Here is the change
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @channel }
end
```

It works perfectly but seems really hackish. There has to be a better, more "Ruby" way. Do I have the syntax wrong on my routes entry? It seems like routes is where this should be.

I know I have to be missing something. I couldn't find good information on this problem on Google or on StackOverflow. That generally means I'm way out in the weeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just put the format.html first. That way, when IE sends a weird accepts header (like `*/*`), it doesn't get fouled up.  Basically, if IE says it accepts everything (like when there is no extension on the URL) Rails will send it the first thing that matches.

Comment: That was one of the things I had considered and for whatever reason I had not tried it.

Comment: +1 for using "wonky" in your title. This is the rails 2.0 IE Accepts header issue. Google for "rails ie accepts".